# How do I point Apache document root to a specific folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a site that the root points to /var/www
I have set up two folders under /var/www

1. /var/www/old
2. /var/www/new

for the old folder, I have used the following to deny any access:

```
touch /var/www/old/.htaccess && echo deny from all >> /var/www/old/.htaccess
```

I now want the server to point the root to /var/www/new so that when people visit http://example.com the content in /var/www/new will serve, what should I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Ubuntu the Apache configuration is located at **/etc/apache2**. There should be two folders, **sites-available** and **sites-enabled**. Inside sites-enabled are symlinks to config files in sites-available.

You simply have to change the document root in your activated configuration. Thats probably **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default**

Have a look for **DocumentRoot** and change it to **/var/www/new**, then reload your apache.

Answer (score 3):

depends a LOT on how your apache server is configured.

I don't have an Ubuntu machine around, but what you're looking for is the DocumentRoot directive. On RedHat based machines it's normally in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf but if memory serves Debian based systems use apache instead of httpd.

If that doesn't work be sure to check in /etc/httpd/conf.d since the files there are loaded dynamically.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried $ ls /etc/httpd but there is no such directory, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf